# libphp7.so not found termux

Tags: php, apache

I m trying to run php-apache server on my android device but i m getting error while httpd file configuration.
**httpd.conf**

```
LoadModule php7_module 
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
<FilesMatch \.php$>
SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>


apachectl start
httpd: Syntax error on line 67 of /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/etc/apache2/httpd.conf: Cannot load /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so into server: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so" not found
```

**php version**

```
PHP 8.1.3 (cli) (built: Apr 13 2022 04:18:15) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.3, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
```

**httpd version**

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.53 (Unix)
Server built:   Mar 15 2022 06:47:59
```

Comment: You are missing part of your PHP/Apache installation. You might have a PHP module installation conflict 1) **apt update && apt upgrade** 2) Reboot the server. 3) **apt install libapache2-mod-php7.4** 4) Run those commands with sudo. 5) My guess is that you have partially installed both PHP 7.x and 8.x .

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
LoadModule php7_module /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

with

```
LoadModule php_module /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/libexec/apache2/libphp.so
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Your path will not exist on other systems. Provide details on why this will solve the problem.